# Broadcasting a numpy.arange into a multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numba

Suppose I have a 3 dimensional array of zeros

```
Y = np.zeros((2,3,4))
```

and I wished to broadcast a 1 dimensional array to it via the second dimension

```
X = np.arange(3)
```

such that the resulting multidimensional array was

```
Y = [[[ 0. 0. 0. 0.]
      [ 1. 1. 1. 1.]
      [ 2. 2. 2. 2.]]

     [[ 0. 0. 0. 0.]
      [ 1. 1. 1. 1.]
      [ 2. 2. 2. 2.]]]
```

What would be the most pythonic and efficient way of achieving this without loops (or even list comprehensions)? I wish to be able to scale this up with larger dimension sizes and run the code with the numba module, which does not compile with np.tile or np.repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are always starting with a *zeros* array, just add `x` so that it will broadcast

```
>>> y + x[None, :, None]
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]]])
```

[General Broadcasting Rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules)

Or

```
>>> np.add(y, x[None, :, None], out = y)
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]]])
>>> y
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]]])
>>>
```

I wasn't sure you could broadcast using assignment but it sems you can:

```
>>> y[:] = x[None, :, None]
>>> y
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]]])
>>> y[...] = x[None, :, None]
>>> y
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reshape `X` firstly so that it can be broadcasted to `Y.shape` and then use [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) method:

```
Y = np.zeros((2,3,4))  
np.broadcast_to(X[:,None], Y.shape)

#array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [2, 2, 2, 2]],

#       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [2, 2, 2, 2]]])
```

---

Another option is, create a new empty array with the same shape as `Y` and then assign X values to it:

```
new_X = np.empty_like(Y)    
new_X[:] = X[:,None]

new_X
#array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
#        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]],

#       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
#        [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]]])
```

Comment: Ah that's something I missed looking through the numpy documentation, works like a charm. Only issue is, its not one of the accepted numpy functions for the numba module.

Comment: I am not familiar with `numba`. so can't give you much suggestion. You might try the `numpy` solution firstly, if it's still not efficient enough, then resort to `numba`.